# Значение из регулярного выражения прописать атрибуту

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток. Есть скрипт, который в тексте ищет название аккордов и прописывает их в путь к картинкам, но перед этим заменяет символы аккордов, которые не допустимы в пути к файлам. Нужно в значение атрибута alt прописать название аккорда до замены символов.

```
var regex = /([ACDEFGH][b#]?[m]?[\(]?(2|5|6|7|9|11|13|6\/9|7\-5|7\-9|7 \#5|7\#9|7\+5|7\+9|7b5|7b9|7sus2|7sus4|add2|add4|add9|aug|dim|dim 7|m\|maj7|m6|m7|m7b5|m9|m11|m13|maj|maj7|maj9|maj11|maj13|mb5|m|s us|sus2|sus4){0,2}(\/[A-H])?(\))?)(?=\s|\.|\)|-|\/)/g;
    var chords = $('.pre').text().match(regex); // получаем аккорды
    // формируем массив только с уникальными
    chords = chords.filter(function(value, index, self) {
        return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    });
    // заменяем символы
    chords = chords
    .join(' ')
    .replace(/\+/g, 'p')
    .replace(/\-/g, 'z')
    .replace(/\#/g, 'w')
    .replace(/\//g, 's')
    .split(' ');
    var content = '';
    // формируем строчку с изображениями
    chords.forEach(function(value) {
        content += '<img src="assets/app/img/chords/' + value + '.png" class="chord" alt="'+ значение аккорда до замены символов +'">';
    });
    $('.tab_chords').append(content);
```

Comment: Непонятно, в чём именно у вас возникли затруднения. Приведите пожалуйста **минимальный** пример кода, который воспроизводит проблему.

Comment: Да, ещё пожалуйста поправьте заголовок. В нём должно быть краткое описание сути проблемы (а не просьба о помощи).

Comment: Проблемы в коде нет. Он сейчас работает, но моих знаний хватает только, что бы вывести в alt аккорды в которых скрипт уже заменил символы. Мне нужно вывести аккорды в alt до замены символов. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// заменяем символы и сохраняем результат в новый массив
var titleChords = chords
  .join(' ')
  .replace(/\+/g, 'p')
  .replace(/\-/g, 'z')
  .replace(/\#/g, 'w')
  .replace(/\//g, 's')
  .split(' ');

var content = '';

// формируем строчку с изображениями
// alt - значение из массива chords
// src - значение из массива titleChords с соответствующим индексом
chords.forEach(function(value, index) {
  content += '<img alt="' + value + '" src="/images/chords/' + titleChords[index] + '_0.gif" />';
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Снова вы мне помогли))